# Why does my Pole Position 2 Cart play Qbert?

Tags: atari-2600, pole-position

A guy I work with just gave me his Atari 2600 and a bunch of games, I hooked it up and thought what should be the first game I try (after 5 hours of playing Destiny) so I popped in Pole Position I figured of all the games in the box this one would show off what the 2600 could really do... Power ON... then Q-Bert...what the heck?

TL:DR My Pole Position 2 Cart plays Qbert ...

Comment: Could you provide a photo of the cart? Maybe the label was swapped?

Comment: I left it at home I can upload one later, but I tried to peel back the label to see if that was the case, it seemed legit. I figured if it was a common thing that google would know but nada

Comment: Also check the backside screw for any suspicious markings. The board could also have been swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer is because it's a Qbert cart and not a Pole Position cart. Somebody either swapped the labels or swapped the boards.

Why anybody would do such a thing remains a mystery.

Comment: I wondered if something crazy was happening like the cart was "incompatible with my atari version and that it was playing qbert as a "backup plan" similar to the way the sega master system had built in games